# TypeError: piegraph is not a function

Tags: javascript, plotly, typeerror

So I have:

```
function graphing(type)
{   

var batches=[];
var labels=[];
var gd=0;
var elementID = "graph";

if(type="truck")
{
    for(var i = 0; i < allTrucks.trucks.length; i++)
    {
        labels.push(allTrucks.trucks[i].display);
        batches.push(allTrucks.trucks[i].loads);
    }
    piegraph(labels,batches,elementID);
}
}
```

And Piegraph() looks like this, but both graphing() and piegraph() are in the same file. Piegraph() is created after graphing()

```
function piegraph(labels, numbers, elementID)
{
piegraph = document.getElementById(elementID);
var data = [{
    values: numbers,
    labels: labels,
    type: 'pie'
}];
var layout = {
    height: 400,
    width: 500
    };
Plotly.newPlot(piegraph, data, layout);
}
```

Main JS File:

```
$('#truck-graph-btn').click(function(){
    graphing("truck");
});
```

I have been trying to figure out this for a few hours. The error is the same as the title "TypeError: piegraph is not a function" I have also searched on here but I none of the fixes I found solved the issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the `HTML` as well ?

Comment: I believe `piegraph = document.getElementById(elementID);` is overwriting your function with a variable.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I could, but its JSP and it is all working correctly (I have it outputting to a modal, and it was working.) Do you still need it?

Comment: Just give the variable a different name `pieGraphElement = document.getElementById(elementID);`

Comment: That seems to work!  Thank you @DavidVereb and @Sushanth!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe piegraph = document.getElementById(elementID); is overwriting your function with a variable. As specified by David Vereb solved my question.